# Best practices in database changes in web applications already deployed

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am trying to find a standard approach on the following problem I have.
I have a web application deployed in a container (specifically Tomcat) and it uses a database for its functionality (in my case it is an SQL database in file mode, so there is no back-end SQL server).

What I am interested in is what is the best way to handle the various changes of my database on newer versions of my web application as the database schema changes (new tables/ new columns, removal of columns etc).
I.e. how can I handle the case of someone upgrading to a newer version of my web application and still retain his old data from the old database in the best (automatic? seemless? less manual?) manner.

I think that this is not a rare case so I believe there some best practice I can follow here.
Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: That depends on how the database would be updated. Are you dropping/recreating tables or using alter table statements?

Comment: @Thomas:Right now I don't have any plan on the update at all.That is why I am asking this.How to do it

Comment: @Thomas:I mean I don't know how it should be updated

Answer (score 5):

Recently we discovered [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org) - it works pretty well and embraces versioning of database schema changes (plain SQL scripts).

Obviously this topic is much broader. For instance you need to be extra careful when both the old and the new version of the application should run flawlessly in updated schema. Also you should consider rollback strategy (when upgrade didn't work well or you want to downgrade your application) - sometimes it is as simple as removing added objects (tables, columns), but when your scripts *removes* something, rollback should restore them.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd want to keep changes to the database and especially to existing columns as low as possible.

Second, if you need to rename a column or change some constraints (be careful not to get more restrictive because there might be some data that would not match), use `ALTER TABLE` statements. This way the data in the columns is preserved unless you drop columns. :)

Additionally, provide default values for new columns that have constraints (like not null) because there might already be datasets in that table that need to be updated in order not to violate those constraints. (Alternatively add the column, run some code to fill the column and then add the constraint.)

Third, since there seem to be multiple users of your application and they might have different versions, the easiest way for providing updates is to provide for sequential updates to the next higher version. Thus if someone wants to update from version 2 to 5, you'd first do the 2->3 update, then 3->4 and finally 4->5.

This might take longer to run but should reduce complexity since you'd bot have to worry about all possible combinations (e.g. 2->4, 2->5, 3->5 etc.)

Comment: But how is the upgrade process supposed to handle this?E.g. if my application is delivered via an RPM and my database is a file object SQL database how/when are the scripts supposed to run?I can't get the overall design

Comment: @Jim the applications that I know have a separate update process for that and you normally manually enable it and it disables itself after running. If you have a RPM distribution the application might have the update being enabled by default and during startup or the first run the update process would be run by the application if enabled. After the update was successful a flag is set to disable the update during subsequent starts (unless a RPM update happened again in between).